# Flutter : How to declare async function as a variable in Dart?

Tags: flutter, function, dart, async-await

I wanted to declare async function as a variable in Dart? How I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Future<void> Function() myAsyncFunc; 
Future<void> anotherAsyncFunc() async => print('solution');
```